# Organic lawn fertilizer available in the UK?

Tags: lawn, fertilizer, organic

Lots of organic fertilizers on the market but very little information to help choose between them. Can anyone recommend a good one that is available in the UK. Read great things about Milorganite but obviously not available in the UK, anything comparable on the UK market?

Answer (score 2):

No comparable product is available in the UK, unless local councils are producing it.

Organic lawn fertilizers often do not show an NPK readout, so it's difficult to know quite what you're applying and how useful it might be. This site here https://www.lawnsmith.co.uk/topic/fertiliser-advice/organic-lawn-fertilisers has general information on the subject, along with other, useful information, but makes no recommendation regarding different brands of organic lawn fertilizers. There are more becoming available as time goes by (10 years ago, you'd have been lucky to find even one in a box) but as to their efficacy, I suspect its a case of suck it and see, so to speak. I've not tried any of them myself, so can't recommend any particular brand, but many are available on Amazon, plus other outlets. I've just seen a fish, blood and bone one purporting to be for use on lawns, but I wouldn't recommend that - the odour attracts foxes, cats, dogs and probably other creatures, because they like to eat it.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the article above, none of the straight organic fertilisers are that great for lawns per se. However if you combine certain ferts such as Bonemeal (high Phosphate), Hoof & Horn (High Nitrogen) and Sulphate of Potash (High Potassium) then you can create a more balanced NPK. This article explains the ratios needed to do so https://www.relentlessgardener.co.uk/best-organic-fertiliser-lawns/

Comment: Hi Matt, are you the same Matt as the owner of the site you link to?  You must disclose your affiliation if you are